# Golang get sdigital signature from PDF file

Tags: go

How can I get a digital signature data from pdf to verify it with root certificate in GOLANG?

I have example in C# but i cann't find any libs in GO

```
public static void Verify(string file, string root)
        {
            X509Certificate rootcer = new X509Certificate(File.ReadAllBytes(root));
            PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(file));
            SignatureUtil signUtil = new SignatureUtil(pdfDoc);
            IList<string> names = signUtil.GetSignatureNames();
            foreach (string name in names)
            {
                PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = signUtil.ReadSignatureData(name);
                bool wholeDocument = signUtil.SignatureCoversWholeDocument(name);
                bool signatureIntegrityAndAuthenticity = pkcs7.VerifySignatureIntegrityAndAuthenticity(); //Integrity yoxlanmasi 
                                                                                                          
                var certs = pkcs7.GetCertificates(); //imzalayan sertifikatin oxunmasi elecede imza atan sexs haqqinda informasiya 
                try
                {
                    certs[0].Verify(rootcer.GetPublicKey()); // root sertifikatla baqliliqin yoxlanmasi /
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                }
               

            }

        }
```